# I cant setup oracle database connection in eclipse showing following error

Tags: oracle, eclipse

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.setSessionFields(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:948)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.<init>(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:351)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.oracle.JDBCOracleConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCOracleConnectionFactory.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to Oracle DB using sql*plus and sql developer ?

Comment: Yes I can access DB through SQL plus

Comment: How are you making connection to Oracle. Can you paste your Java code as well ?

Comment: This error is not because of code.while connecting server in eclipse (database development tools) it is showing ping failed and then this error.

Answer (score 2):

If you have instance running on local or if you installed Sql Developer with jdk you can add jdbc driver path from either installation directory  i.e from local instance  ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/ or sqldeveloper installed_directory/jdbc/lib

Go to preferences in eclipse,expand connectivity select driver definitions,filter by Oracle and select Oracle thin driver 11 as shown in picture below [image]

Click Jar list tab and delete ojdbc14.jar from the list

[image]

Click Add jar file and point to directory in either Oracle Home or Sql Developer installed directory or  location of `ojdbc8.jar` file if downloaded

[image]

After this close preferences go to Database Perspective create new connection  enter host name,port and service name and click test

[image]

Edit:-It shows default thin driver when creating new connection in order to verify you can click edit triangle part that shows your jdbc driver as shown in picture below

[image]

P.S:- I read your comments again not sure if you're using Oracle Instant client or have local instance but you can download individual jar files or full package  `ojdbc8-full.tar.gz` from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html) website

Edit:- Whenever connection fails i.e ping failed check for the message on top of error stack.For e.g for wrong password

`java.sql.SQL.Exception:ORA-01017:invalid username/password:logon denied`This message is very important to trouble shoot connection problems on the other hand if you don't see any message most probably Oracle thin driver did not load.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have installed oracle 11g .Did the same. Added required libraries still showing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It's Ecipse feature/bag. Unfortunately in Oracle thin driver template it expected SID not service name. that's why url will be

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:db
```

instead of

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/db
```

Only solution is choose Other Oracle Driver and on proerties tab add template with "/"